# how to send fake sms to my Android Device

Tags: android, sms

I want to send fake sms on android, but I couldn't do it.

My code below:

```
      Intent a = new Intent("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");

      byte[] by =(byte[])(SmsMessage.getSubmitPdu("12345", "1234", "hello", false).encodedMessage);
      Object[] vrs = {by};
      a.putExtra("pdus",vrs);
      sendBroadcast(a);
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Depends on what the purpose is. If you just want a new item in the sms list, I'd just grab the sqlite database and insert a new entry using the sqlite cmd-line tool. I've used the method to send myself text messages and then change who they came from for various nefarious purposes..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some broadcasts are protected and can only be sent by the System. Maybe this is one of those.

UPDATE
This snippet from the Android SMS application might help you.

```
<!-- Require sender permissions to prevent SMS spoofing -->
<receiver android:name=".transaction.PrivilegedSmsReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In short, try asking for the BROADCAST_SMS permission

for further reference http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

Comment: Sorry guys for the bad answer. Will take care of this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Check your manifest file and sure give these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```